# awk: how to filter out a row that all entries (16 columns) are 0

Tags: csv, filter, awk

My CSV file is delimited by tab, and I want to filter out those rows that have all entries (in 16 columns) of 0 value. I am now doing this

```
awk '$1 != 0 && $2 != 0 && ....omitted && $16 != 0 {print $0}' file.csv > newFile.csv
```

As you can see this is so tiring for inputing the same conditions for all 16 columns. Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this (assuming you have 16 fields throughout)

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=16; ++i) if($i != 0) {print;next}}' file.csv > newFile.csv
```

Comment: I want to filter out the row only if all the entries are 0. I guess this code removes an entry as long as it is 0, right?

Comment: @TonyGW,nopes, this filters out the row if all entries are 0

Comment: More to the point it only prints the row if some entry *isn't* zero.

Answer (score 5):

What about something like

```
grep -Ev '^0+([[:space:]]+0+){15}$' file.csv
```

or

```
awk --posix '!/^0+([[:space:]]+0+){15}/'
```

Comment: Required for the `{}` range to work according to the man page. That or `--re-interval`.

Comment: +1; re `--posix`: as of at least GNU awk 4.0.1 (don't know if and when that changed), `{}` quantifiers are supported by default (you can turn them _off_ with `--traditional` (has other implications too)). Similarly, FreeBSD awk (e.g., on OSX) supports them by default. Other awk flavors don't support them at all (e.g., mawk, which doesn't support `--posix` either); comparison - albeit dated - [here](http://awk.freeshell.org/AwkFeatureComparison)

Answer (score 3):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) can do this as well:

```
sed -n '/[^0\t]/p' file.csv
```

This command prints the line only if there's a character which is different from `0` and `\t` (tab). Alternatively you can also do:

```
sed '/[^0\t]/!d' file.csv
```

Deleting all lines that do not (`!`) match the regex `[^0\t]`.